# Eclipse - open an existing project and import projects on to it through command line

Tags: eclipse, command-line, import

I want to run eclipse on a certain workspace and have some projects already imported to it.
I've tried eclipse's `-import` command line option, but it hasn't imported anything.

Is there a way to do that, **without plugins**, through the command line?

Comment: you only can achive this by an ant task. you can run ant ant file by  eclipsec -nosplash -data /path/to/workspace -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -buildfile /path/to/ant-file.xml

Comment: I don't know if I have ant on my environment

Comment: if you have an eclipse default installation then you have ant. you only have to write an ant task.

Comment: how should this file look like? which slot is used for  imports?